# How can I use VB.net to pass Excel parameters to a user defined excel formula?

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, vb.net-2010

With vb.net I would like to select 4 cells in Excel and then pass those cell values along with 1 button tag to a formula in Excel.

I press a button with a month, say "May" as text. I want to grab a cell in Excel labeled "May1t" the value of which is the number of hours until may. This is the code I'm using.

xlsWB.Worksheets(2).Range(Month1 & "1t").Value

I am able to set a variable with this as the value but,

I want to pass this cell (which will be updating as the time counts down) and 3 other similarly specified cells along with the button tag to an Excel formula.

I have something like this:

```
Private Sub F_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles F.Click

    xlsWB.Worksheets(4).Range("B2").Formula = "=MyFunction()"
    xlsWB.Worksheets(1).Range(Month1 & "1t").Select()

End Sub
```

The formula takes the parameters in the order: MyFunction(Cell,Tag,Cell,Cell,Cell).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Cell & Tag are strings, can you just go?:

```
xlsWB.Worksheets(4).Range("B2").Formula =
"=MyFunction(" & Cell & "," & Tag & "," & Cell & "," & Cell & "," & Cell & ")"
```